# How can I uninstall a locale via command-line?

Tags: uninstall, locale

I have 5 unused locales on my system. How can I remove them via command line? I have use `localepurge` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can list locales with

```
localedef --list-archive
```

or with

```
locale -a
```

Corresponding file size is given by

```
ls -lh /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

To remove unused locales you can do

```
sudo locale-gen --purge it_IT.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && echo 'Success!'
```

where `it_IT.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` are the **only two locales I want**. The `&& echo 'Success!'` at end is useful because `locale-gen` does not report errors if an unavailable or wrong locale is passed on command line.

Comment: The command for 12.04 is `localedef --list-archive` without `s`

Comment: @techtonik: it is so also in 11.10, my errror :)

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to remove just the locales that I don't need? I am not sure whichever of en_US locales are used - I prefer to leave them all and remove only the ones that I am absolutely sure have no use on my system, like de_*.

Comment: On bash the exclamation mark in the `"Succes!"` string triggers the bash history expansion. To avoid this problem you have to include `'Success!'` into single quotes or (strangely!) remove the quotes. From [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction): _History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion character, which is ‘!’ by default. Only `\ ` and `'` may be used to escape the history expansion character._

Comment: --purge is not working in my case and is not documented...

Comment: It did not work for me either

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 22.04), I have about 24 locales (listed by `localedef --list-archive`) - one Czech `cs_CZ.utf8` and the rest are just variants of English, e.g. `en_CA.utf8`, `en_GB.utf8`, `en_US.utf8`, etc. But when I ran [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org) (a GUI file cleaning tool), it has found various locale and localization files in various locations (e.g. `/usr/share/man/`, `/usr/share/help/`) in dozens of languages not listed by `localedef`, the total of about 500 MB of data. I'm not sure why they're even installed, maybe installations that don't check what locales are enabled?